# VBA Code for User-Defined IFS Function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

Our firm uses the packaged version of Excel 2016, and not the Office 365 version.  I've recently learned of the IFS function present in the newer versions, and it seems incredibly useful.  I've found the CONCATENATEIF function here on the site in VBA form, and I'm wondering if there's a way to replicate this formula in my older version in the same way.  I'm not very experienced in VBA coding, so I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) and [ask].

Comment: This https://t7training.com.au/excel-ifs-function appears to indicate that you can fix this with an update

Answer (score 2):

The following reproduces the functionality of `IFS()`, using `ParamArray` to handle an arbitrary number of parameters:

```
Public Function UdfIfs(ParamArray args() As Variant) As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 0 ' or 1 if you're not using zero-based indexing
  Do Until CBool(args(i)) Or (i >= UBound(args))
    i = i + 2
  Loop
  If i < UBound(args) Then
    UdfIfs = args(i + 1)
  End If
End Function
```