# Creating a custom IFS code in non Office 365 excel versions?

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, excel-2016

I've read that the function  `IFS`  isn't available in Excel version 2016 (that it's not 365).

Is there a way to write a custom code that does just what `IFS` do but in Excel 2016?

How can I do it? Where do I write it? Please bear with me; I have no programming or coding experience. I use Excel as a freelancer and stumbled upon the IFS formula, but I can't use it. It would be a lifesaver if you guys could teach me how.

I don't want to come across as demanding, but if the result of that code is that I can use the function as any other, I would be so thankful!

Comment: [What about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462892/vba-code-for-user-defined-ifs-function-in-excel)?

Comment: It appears to be so, but I'm not sure where to copy it or how to apply it to my own language (Spanish). If the language changes, do the formulas change as well? Or is it just the name that changes?

Comment: Open the VB Editor (Alt + F11), insert a new module, and paste the code in it. The functionality of the formula remains the same, even if the name changes between English and Spanish versions.

Comment: YES! Thank you. It works :). I Wish I had points to give you.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, why didn't you shared the solution, then could have voted up for the trick using `UDF`

Comment: Because the question is a duplicate. Feel free to upvote the answer in the linked thread.